# My GitHub Pages site doesn't appear in google search index

Tags: google-search-console

Yesterday, I created my [GitHub pages site](https://kirusha05.github.io/) and I tried to add in the google search index. Here's what I did:

I went to  google search console and added new "property" with "URL prefix".

Then I added the meta tag on my github-pages site (html-head) as described, it looked like

Then I pasted my page URL (kirusha05.github.io) to the "search bar" on the top of the search console

I was redirected to URL adress verification page, where I saw "URL adress is not on Google". I clicked "request indexing". A live test started , then a message like "The live test failed" showed up.

I saw again "URL adress is not on Google" . This page is not included in index , but not because of an error. And under that a Coverage section, near it I saw "Google doesn't know the URL adress" . What is wrong ? How can I get my site indexed ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome here.

```
Yesterday, I created my GitHub pages site
```

Keep calm and wait. This helps always. Then write good content. Earn good backlinks. It can take (much) time, till you see your site in SERP. Some new sites are indexed fast - some slow.

Look at the list of same threads, https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=my+site+is+not+indexed - you'll find multiple equivalent cases with same recommendations. Keep calm, again - there is nothing weird or broken with your site.

The only thing i see - your site has nearly no content. Google should get a cause to come and to index your site. Create the cause - two sentences are too pure.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. Would it be ok if I add on my site a complex description of my program?

Comment: Holy moly, it worked . If I search `kirusha05 calculator` on google , my site and the project repository appears. Yeaaah, I'm so happy. I didn't believe this was possible. And just to mention , after your name , I think you're russian, like me :).